# TSLINT config : exclude external modules

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, linter

I'm using angular2 webpack starter with tslint configured on it.

I also use ngx-datables (directory @swimlane directly in node_modules).

I have plenty of warnings like :

```
 @ ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/utils/index.ts 14:0-32
 @ ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/components/datatable.component.ts
 @ ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/components/index.ts
 @ ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/adherent/list/adherent-list.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/adherent/list/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/adherent/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts
```

However, my configs are supposed to be well done :

tsconfig.json :

```
...
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
...
```

tsconfig.webpack.json :

```
...
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.e2e.ts"
  ],
...
```

tslint.json :

```
...
"exclude": [
     "node_modules"
  ],
...
```

I've also tried with `"**/node_modules/**"`. But nothing changed, i still have the warnings.

Comment: I believe this been fixed now, since you could `**/node-modules/**`  or `**/<folder-name>/**for sub folders and it's content.
I'm using tslint 5.20.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the same angular2-starter with webpack, the solution for me was add `node_modules` folder to exclude, it was inside the `webpack.dev.js` file, I have changed:

```
exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
```

to

```
exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
```

And worked, the solution that provided from @Aravind not worked sadly.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using /** for all folders inside it

```
"exclude": [
     "node_modules/**"
  ],
...
```

Comment: this worked strangely better than the original : /node_modules/

Thank you :) !